# How to update the DOM after jQuery .load()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, load

I'd like to load html content from a template file (b.xhtml), insert it to the calling file (a.xhtml) and then update the inserted node (e.g. add/delete attributes etc.).

The insertion part works fine, but the DOM doesn't seem to get updated.

Here's the test case.

**a.xhtml** (the calling html file)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("button").click(function(){
                $("#placeholder").load("b.xhtml #id2");
                // why doesn't this work?
                var myTemp = document.querySelector("#id2");
                if (myTemp) {
                    alert(myTemp.innerHTML);
                } else {
                    alert("#id2 is undefined");
                };
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>jQuery load test</h1>
    <div><button>Load template</button></div>
    <div id="placeholder"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**b.xhtml** (the template html file)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="templates">
        <p id="id1">This is template one</p>
        <p id="id2">This is template two</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

1. How do I update the DOM after **.load()**?
2. Is there an easier method to insert HTML nodes from an external HTML file that'll automatically update the DOM?
3. Alternatively, how can I change or add an attribute of the node from b.xhtml before (or after) it's inserted in a.xhtml? For example, how would I add an alt="template text" attribute to the #id2 node?

Comment: Use `load()` complete callback, because it is async.

Comment: Inserting new elements in the DOM will trigger a (sic) 'reflow', which will run after the current script stops executing. So the element isn't in the DOM yet when you try selecting it. Use the callback as described below, which will only trigger after that reflow has completed. Or use a defer to queue javascript after the reflow, which more or less does the same. (if i'm not mistaking, that's what jquery will do in the background.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The .load() method is asynchronous, so your script is executing that line but not waiting for it to finish before it goes on to the next line. You can do a couple things. First, use a callback function:

```
$("#placeholder").load("b.xhtml #id2", function(){
            var myTemp = document.querySelector("#id2");
            if (myTemp) {
                alert(myTemp.innerHTML);
            } else {
                alert("#id2 is undefined");
            };
});
```

Or, use .done():

```
$("#placeholder").load("b.xhtml #id2").done(function(){
            var myTemp = document.querySelector("#id2");
            if (myTemp) {
                alert(myTemp.innerHTML);
            } else {
                alert("#id2 is undefined");
            };
});
```

Comment: I'm attempting to use the .done method, but I'm getting the error `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).load(...).done is not a function` - any thoughts? I'm using jQuery 3.1.0. The line in question is `$("#song").load("http://kvrx.org #track-name:eq(0)").done(function(){track['trackTitle'] = song.innerHTML});` - I'm trying to update an objects (defined just above this line) trackTitle property.

Comment: Thanks, this one got me as well. load() doesn't seem to treat a function pointer in its second argument as a done() asynch return, had to use an anonymous function there just to call the function pointer. (It may be an error on my part, still kind of a complex setup by the seat of my pants)

Answer (score 1):

Try to do it like this:

```
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("button").click(function(){
                $("#placeholder").load("b.xhtml #id2",function()
                {
                    var myTemp = document.querySelector("#id2");
                    if (myTemp) {
                      alert(myTemp.innerHTML);
                    } else {
                      alert("#id2 is undefined");
                    };
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but **Cruiser** was one minute faster than you and also offered two solutions. :-(