# How do I change placeholder content in javascript per page

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

How do I update content loaded with Jquery `.load()` with javascript?

I'm using two placeholders on every page: one with the navigation bar, and one with the main skeleton of the content, like this:

```
    <body>
      <div id="nav-placeholder">
      </div>
      <div id="content-placeholder">
      </div>
    </body>
```

The nav bar and content are both in seperate files and are loaded into the pages with an external javascript file like this:

```
$(function(){
  $("#nav-placeholder").load("nav.html");
});

$(function(){
  $("#content-placeholder").load("content.html");
});
```

So far, it all works nicely. Now, I'm trying to alter the content separately for each page (with JS)

Part of `content.html` is for example

```
<h2 id="subheader1">Title</h2>
```

I'm trying to change the `#subheader1` content in the javascript file like so:

```
$(function(){
  $("#nav-placeholder").load("nav.html");
});

$(function(){
  $("#content-placeholder").load("content.html");
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  document.getElementById("subheader1").outerHTML = "test" ;
});
```

but that doesn't work (this is aimed at all pages, but it still doesn't work). Probably because it's only seeing the placeholder DIV in index.html and not it's content?

I tried placing the subheader1 div in the `index.html` to test, and then it did work, but that would take away the efficiency of the placeholder.

Is there any way to do this (or another way to be more efficient with pages with the same (DIV) layout but different text?)

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you use callback to change the outerHTML to test? or perform operation after it is successful?

Comment: @RajeshPaudel Good idea, tried it, but still doesn't work unfortunately.

Comment: Could you update with what you tried once.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to update the DOM after jQuery .load()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38147015/how-to-update-the-dom-after-jquery-load)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `load` method is not synchronous, so

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  document.getElementById("subheader1").outerHTML = "test" ;
});
```

is executed before the html is loaded in the page.

The [doc](https://api.jquery.com/load/) suggest using a callback function.

> it is executed after post-processing and HTML insertion has been performed

I had success using this in my js file:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(function(){
        $("#nav-placeholder").load("./nav.html", function() {
            document.getElementById("insideNav").outerHTML = "It works !" ;
        });
    });
});
```

with `<h2 id="insideNav">Original Nav Bar</h2>` in my `nav.html`.